# Data are not showing in label

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I have one collection view which have to display only the category name and its image. And if user click any collection view cell, It will go to next vc and it will show the respective name, images.

But when i pass the value to my label its not showing in my screen. But while put print statement. It showing the value.Here is my code

My first vc segue :

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {

        if (segue.identifier == "CollectionToDetail")
        {

            if let indexPath2 = getIndexPathForSelectedCell2()
            {
                let DealsdetailViewController = segue.destination as!MoreDetailVC

                DealsdetailViewController.Productdata =  [Productdata[(indexPath2 as NSIndexPath).row]]

              print(Productdata[(indexPath2 as NSIndexPath).row].catID)
            }
        }

    }
```

In my second VC :

```
 var Productdata = [ProductData]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ProductName.text = Productdata[0].catName

        print(ProductName.text)
}
```

But my `ProductName.text = Productdata[0].catName` is not showing any value on my screen . please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: By declaring it `var Productdata = [ProductData]()`, aren't creating a new one?

Comment: That is my nsobject class, for storing all value

Comment: but in my print statement i am getting the catName as  :  `Optional("Laptops")`

Comment: @mack  i give you answer check it and print it

Comment: @mack send me new project on my mail i just remove it so

Comment: Why do you declare an array in the second view controller, since you're obviously passing always only one object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In my second VC :**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //self.ProcatId = Productdata[0].catID

      //  print(self.ProcatId)
        ProductName.text = self.Productdata[0].catName

        print(ProductName.text)

 GetAdValues()

}
 func GetAdValues()
    {
        ProductName.text = Productdata[0].catName!

        print(ProductName.text)

        self.load_image((Productdata[0].proImage)!)

      //  let BDetails = Dealsdata?.DealBusinessDetails

      //  self.BusinessData.append(Businessdata(json:BDetails!))

    }
func load_image(_ urlString:String)
    {
        let imgURL: URL = URL(string: urlString)!

        let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: imgURL)

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil && data != nil)
            {
                func display_image()
                {
                    self.ProductImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: display_image)
            }

        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

[image: output]

Comment: its same project ? that i have ?

Comment: adding self to Productdata isn't neccessary at all and doesn't solve the issue

Comment: @mack is there same project ?

Comment: @mack then give me time i just open it and look it

Comment: @mack look your last question message i have little query in your projecty

Comment: In your project what is businessdata and all i have work fine with this one wait i send you that project @mack